# Notation about the torus

Tags: general-topology

Given $T>0$, I wonder how the torus $\mathbb{T}_T^N=\mathbb{R}^N/(T\mathbb{Z})^N$ can be expressed in terms of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the cartesian product. For instante, I know $\mathbb{T}^N=\mathbb{R}^N/\mathbb{Z}^N=\mathbb{S}^1×...×    \mathbb{S}^1   $. Thanks!

Comment: What does $T\Bbb Z$ denote here?

Comment: T is a positive number. Sorry, I didnt say. I have edited it.

Comment: Therefore $T\mathbb{Z} =\lbrace tp:p\in\mathbb{Z} \rbrace$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $\Bbb R^n / (T\Bbb Z)^N$ is still homoemorphic (indeed, diffeomorphic!) to $S^1 \times \ldots \times S^1$. I don't think that there's any special notation for it. Perhaps as Lie groups there's something interesting to be said, or (for $N$ even) there's something useful to say in terms of complex manifolds ... but from the point of view of topology (which is what the problem is tagged as), these things are "the same".